# Expanding Multiple Lists beyond four lists with tocbasic

Tags: lists, tocbasic

I am using package `tocbasic` under `report`, and have successfully expanded the lists to include two new ones, however, I need a third new list. I have entered `\DeclareNewTOC` successfully and get the new item and can refer to it with `\autoref` successfully but I do not get a fifth listing and unstable change occurs to List of Tables changing to the listing title I want but the items are still tables. Specifically:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
.
.
.
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries{tocline}{figure,table}
DeclareNewTOC[%
type=map
.
.
%this works fine

\DeclareNewToc[%
type=graph
.
.
%this works fine
DeclareNewToc[%
type=flow,
float,
name=Flow Diagrams},
counterwithin=chapter,
setup=totoc,   %this does not work
tocentryindent:=figure
tocentryunumwidth:=figure
]{lofn}

\begin{document}

\begin{flow}
\include....
\label{flow}
\end{flow}
\end{document}
```

This works fine in text with correct textual reference identification with `\autoref` but no list appears.

How do I fix this?  Excuse any typos.
thanks.

Comment: Welcome! It is going to be hard for people to help you without code. Unless somebody happens to know the package and the problem or can guess, there's nothing here to work with. I'd suggest editing your question and providing a complete minimal example which people can compile to reproduce the problem. So no `...` or `\include...` because that won't compile.